# How to zoom the excel window?

Tags: excel, powershell

I am doing a powershell script that creates a new excel file and I would like that when the file opens, the zoom of the page is at 85%.

Someone has an idea of ​​how?

```bsh
$NewExcel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$NewExcel.visible = $True
$NewExcel.WindowState = "xlMaximized"
$NewWorkbook = $NewExcel.Workbooks.Add()
$NewWorksheet= $NewWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
```

This is my script to create the worksheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found !

```
Function Set-XlColumns {
$Window = $NewExcel.ActiveWindow
$Window.Zoom = 80
}
Set-XlColumns
```

Just use this function and call it later